# Installing matplotlib using pip RHEL getting error "Cannot uninstall 'pyparsing' "

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, rhel

I am currently using RHEL7 and am trying to install matplotlib. When ever i have attempted to do

`python -m pip install -U matplotlib`

or

`pip install matplotlib`

I get the error message "*Cannot uninstall 'pyparsing'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall*."

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if you need more information I can provide it.

Comment: Try uninstalling `pyparsing` through `pip uninstall pyparsing`. Then try installing `matplotlib`.

Comment: It doesn't allow me to uninstall 'pyparsing' using pip either unfortunately. I got the same error code

Comment: Are you using a [virtual environment](https://www.sitepoint.com/virtual-environments-python-made-easy/) to install `matplotlib`? If not please try.

Comment: Is the only way to use matplotlib with a virtual environment?

Comment: Of course not the only way.

Comment: I'm trying to do this without using a virtual environment. I want to use python directly without using the virtual environment

Comment: Apparently, someone even [made a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yxL5Dk3LYiM) on a possible workaround.

Comment: [This comment may be helpful](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5247#issuecomment-381550610).

Comment: Did you install `pyparsing` via `yum`? What does `yum list installed | grep -i pyparsing` return? Also, what Python version is it (`python -V`)?

Comment: When i attempt to install pyparsing via yum I get "Package pyparsing-1.5.6-9.e17.noarch already installed and latest version." 

And then the "yum list installed | grep - pyparsing" returns:

pyparsing.noarch      1.5.6-9.el7     @anaconda/7.5

I don't want to be using the anaconda at all. I just want to use Python 3.7, but currently Python 2.7.5 and Python 3.7.1 are installed on my machine.

Comment: Also @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I tried the workaround in the video and now i'm getting "error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1."

Comment: Looks like `python` refers to Python 2.7.5 on your machine. If you need `matplotlib` for Python 2.7.5, install a more recent version of `pyparsing` as user, e.g.: `pip install --user "pyparsing==2.3.0"`. Now you should be able to install `matplotlib` as intended: `pip install --user matplotlib`. If you need it for Python 3.7, use the correct executable: `python3.7 -m pip install --user matplotlib`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `pip` cannot properly uninstall packages installed by "pure" `distutils` (see the details [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5247)).

You can fix the problem by deleting `pyparsing` by hands:

Firstly, you need to determine the path to the package:

```sh
$ pip list -v | grep pyparsing
```

You will see something like:

```
pyparsing           2.0.1              /path_to_the_python/site-packages
```

Then take this *path* and delete the package (mind the asterisk):

```sh
$ rm -rf  /path_to_the_python/site-packages/pyparsing*
```

And install it again:

```sh
$ pip install pyparsing
```

Comment: I am using MacOS (Big Sur) and I cannot delete those files even using sudo